# Parse error in a case expression - haskell

Tags: haskell, case, parse-error

I get a parse error on this code and am not sure as to why, please help. I am also very new to haskell so forgive the very simple question.

```
intDiv a b = case a b of 
    b==0 -> Just(1)
    _ -> Nothing
```

error message is:

```
Q66827743.hs:4:5: error: Parse error in pattern: b == 0
  |
4 |     b==0 -> Just(1)
  |     ^^^^
```

Comment: `case a b of` means "call function `a` with argument `b`, and then check the result". I guess this is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have conflated `case of` syntax with guard syntax.

When using `case of`, you don't 'guard' on Boolean expressions; you match on patterns:

```
intDiv a b = case a b of 
    0 -> Just 1
    _ -> Nothing
```

This function doesn't make much sense, but it compiles.

If you want to guard on Boolean expressions, you can do that as well, but the syntax is different:

```
intDiv a b | b == 0 = Just 1
intDiv _ _ = Nothing
```

This variation also compiles.

Note that the two variations are *not* equivalent, since they don't have the same (inferred) type.